# Digits in factorial numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Several of my students have noticed that the factorial of 23 is the first to contain at least one copy of each of the ten digits, and they wonder whether every sufficiently large factorial similarly contains at least one of each of the ten digits.

I would guess yes, but has this been proved?

Comment: $24!$ does not have any digit $5$ appearing.  "*Arbitrarily large factorial*"... your question seems to be then... does there exist some $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ you have $n!$ has all ten digits appearing in its base-10 representation... noting that $N$ would not be $23$.

Comment: Clarified the issue.

Comment: $25!$ has neither $6$ nor $7$

Comment: $42!$ through $999!$ all have all $10$ digits, so perhaps $42$ is a good candidate.  In python `max(n for n in range(25,1000) if len(set(str(factorial(n)))) != 10)` evaluates to $41$

Comment: Though this doesn't answer the question: in case digits are uniformly distributed in the factorials, one notes that given sufficient digits (or given a large enough factorial), the probability of not finding all 10 digits can be made arbitrarily small

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613467/whats-the-next-base-ten-non-pandigital-factorial-number-after-41

Comment: For $42\le n\le 3\cdot 10^4$ , $n!$ contains all the digits in the base $10$-representation, hence $42$ (the answer to everything :) ) should be the desired $N$.